# Override automatic geocoding for events

Tags: civievent, geocoding

How can i override or update the coordinates for an address on an event that isn't displaying correctly. Seems like the option in wordpress for Override automatic geocoding is missing in drupal - or maybe its elsewhere?

Thanks!

Drupal 7, Civi 5.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Latitude, Longitude fields are only visible when they are enable in 'Address Editing'. To enable it navigate to Administer >> Localization >> Address settings. Check for 'Address Editing' option. Check box for Latitude, Longitude option and save the settings.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep